# Requesting image returns 403/404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I'm using Nginx + Unicorn with my rails 3.0.3 app.

Here's my nginx config for the app:

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  root /home/deployer/apps/myapp/current/public;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Here's the directory listing of the app's `public/images`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deployer admin     56 2012-03-28 17:06 other -> /home/deployer/other_images/
-rw-rw-r--  1 deployer admin   6646 2012-03-28 17:08 rails.png
```

As you can see `other` is a symlink. Here's the directory listing for `/home/deployer/other_images/`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 deployer admin   2271 2012-02-03 17:24 1.jpg
```

In the browser, I can pull up `http://<domain>/images/rails.png` but `http://<domain>/images/other/1.jpg` is returning the `public/404.html` page ("The page you were looking for doesn't exist").

What am I doing wrong? Is it a permissions issue with one of the files/directories? Is my nginx config not setup correctly?

**UPDATE**

When I add the following to the app's nginx config (below the `root`), and request the `1.jpg`, I get back a 403 Permission denied:

```
location ^~ /images/ {
  gzip_static on;
  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The `/home/deployer/other_images` directory didn't have read permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have fixed it, but for others that experience this issue, if it's always good practice to return a 404 after your `try_files` code...

using the example from above

```
try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn =404;
```